# List of list of words by Python:

Tags: python, word-list

Having a long list  of comments (50 by saying) such as this one:

> "this was the biggest disappointment of our trip. the restaurant had
>   received some very good reviews, so our expectations were high. the
>   service was slow even though the restaurant was not very full. I had
>   the house salad which could have come out of any sizzler in the us.
>   the keshi yena, although tasty reminded me of barbequed pulled
>   chicken. this restaurant is very overrated".

I want to create a list of list of words retaining sentence tokenization using python.

After removing stopwords I want a result for all 50 comments in which sentence tokens are retained and word tokens are retained into each tokenized sentence. At the end I hope result being similar to:

```
list(c("disappointment", "trip"), 
     c("restaurant", "received", "good", "reviews", "expectations", "high"), 
     c("service", "slow", "even", "though", "restaurant", "full"),
     c("house", "salad", "come", "us"), 
     c("although", "tasty", "reminded", "pulled"), 
     "restaurant")
```

How could I do that in python? Is R a good option in this case? I really will appreciate your help.

Comment: whats the `c` around the inner list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to create a list of stop words by hand, I would recommend that you use the nltk library in python. It also handles sentence splitting (as opposed to splitting on every period). A sample that parses your sentence might look like this:

```
import nltk
stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
text = "this was the biggest disappointment of our trip. the restaurant had received some very good reviews, so our expectations were high. the service was slow even though the restaurant was not very full. I had the house salad which could have come out of any sizzler in the us. the keshi yena, although tasty reminded me of barbequed pulled chicken. this restaurant is very overrated"
sentence_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
sentences = sentence_detector.tokenize(text.strip())
results = []
for sentence in sentences:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    words = [t.lower() for t in tokens if t.isalnum()]
    not_stop_words = tuple([w for w in words if w not in stop_words])
    results.append(not_stop_words)
print results
```

However, note that this does not give the exact same output as listed in your question, but instead looks like this:

```
[('biggest', 'disappointment', 'trip'), ('restaurant', 'received', 'good', 'reviews', 'expectations', 'high'), ('service', 'slow', 'even', 'though', 'restaurant', 'full'), ('house', 'salad', 'could', 'come', 'sizzler', 'us'), ('keshi', 'yena', 'although', 'tasty', 'reminded', 'barbequed', 'pulled', 'chicken'), ('restaurant', 'overrated')]
```

You might need to add some stop words manually in your case if the output needs to look the same.

Comment: Hi. What if I have separate lines of text and I want to retain separation?  And then, how to save the result in a csv file?

Comment: Well, doesn't each tuple in the list corresponding to a separate sentence within the restaurant review? Just look through the list and get each sentence's non-stop words. Also, to save the contents to a csv file, I would recommend looking at the csv module in python, which can be useful since it is likely you might have commas within each sentence.

Comment: In fact, the example I provided is just a consumer review which has several sentences.  The point is that I've around 50 comments with the same features.

Comment: Then instead of a single "text" string variable, create an array that contains 50 strings, each with an individual review. Write a for loop that goes through the array and executes the code I have written above on each of those strings.

Comment: Thanks. I created a new requirement at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539230/how-to-create-an-rray-of-composites-strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you want R for this or not, but based on your requirement, I think it can be done in a pure pythonic way as well.

You basically want a list that contains small list of important words (that are not stop words) per sentence.

So you can do something like

```
input_reviews = """
this was the biggest disappointment of our trip. the restaurant had received some very good reviews, so our expectations were high. 
the service was slow even though the restaurant was not very full. I had the house salad which could have come out of any sizzler in the us. 
the keshi yena, although tasty reminded me of barbequed pulled chicken. this restaurant is very overrated.
"""

# load your stop words list here
stop_words_list = ['this', 'was', 'the', 'of', 'our', 'biggest', 'had', 'some', 'very', 'so', 'were', 'not']


def main():
    sentences = input_reviews.split('.')
    sentence_list = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        inner_list = []
        words_in_sentence = sentence.split(' ')
        for word in words_in_sentence:
            stripped_word = str(word).lstrip('\n')
            if stripped_word and stripped_word not in stop_words_list:
                # this is a good word
                inner_list.append(stripped_word)

        if inner_list:
            sentence_list.append(inner_list)

    print(sentence_list)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On my end, this outputs

```
[['disappointment', 'trip'], ['restaurant', 'received', 'good', 'reviews,', 'expectations', 'high'], ['service', 'slow', 'even', 'though', 'restaurant', 'full'], ['I', 'house', 'salad', 'which', 'could', 'have', 'come', 'out', 'any', 'sizzler', 'in', 'us'], ['keshi', 'yena,', 'although', 'tasty', 'reminded', 'me', 'barbequed', 'pulled', 'chicken'], ['restaurant', 'is', 'overrated']]
```

Comment: Hi Saif: thanks a lot for your help. Now, how could I save these results in a matrix and in a csv file?

Comment: That is an entirely new requirement and I suggest you open a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. You may need to initialize the `stop_words` as suits your application. I have assumed `stop_words` is in lowercase: hence, using `lower()` on the original sentences for comparison. `sentences.lower().split('.')` gives sentences. `s.split()` gives list of words in each sentence.

```
stokens = [list(filter(lambda x: x not in stop_words, s.split())) for s in sentences.lower().split('.')]
```

You may wonder why we use `filter` and `lambda`. An alternative is this but this will give a flat list and hence is not suitable:

```
stokens = [word for s in sentences.lower().split('.') for word in s.split() if word not in stop_words]
```

`filter` is a functional programming construct. It helps us to process an entire list, in this case, via an anonymous function using the `lambda` syntax.