# How to create an rray of composites strings

Tags: python, arrays, string

Hi everyone: I have a collection of 50 strings that represent comments in a text file where each line represents a separate comment with different sentences .

Each string is a user review of a product, and each string or review has several several sentences.

How could I to create an array with these strings using Python?

Example of reviews:
Review 1.  "I was disapointed with the product. The quality was reality bad and the price was not fair.  Never in my life I'll buy again this brand.

Review 2. "I'm really happy with this product.  It's all what i desired.  Thanks brand J"
.... and so far.

Desired Results:

1. [('disappointed', 'product'), ('quality', 'really', 'bad', 'price', 'fair')]
2. [('happy', 'product'), ('all', 'desired'), ('thanks', 'brand')]
3. ...

I want each processed comment in a separate line to save it in a csv file

Comment: And what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: what does your collection of strings look like?

Comment: My collection of comments is a txt file and each line means a separate review with different sentences.  After apply stopwords I want a result like this: 1. [('disappointed', 'product'), ('quality', 'really', 'bad', 'price', 'fair')]
2. [('happy', 'product'), ('all', 'desired'), ('thanks', 'brand')]
3. ...  I want each processed comment in a separate line to save it in a csv file.

Comment: sorry edited your question so i could understand it better, plus you gave more needed information but didnt put it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

One of my first projects was similar to this. I believe your asking for help in getting the text file lines as an array.

To open the file for reading:

`file = open("/path/to/file", "r")`

I would then split on spaces so:

```
for line in file: 
      print line.split(' ')
```

this would give you an array of words from each line in the txt file. 
Then use the `csv` module in python to input into a csv file.

References:

- [Python the Hard Way - Opening and Closting Files](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)
- [split() function](https://www.dotnetperls.com/split-python)
- [CSV Module](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/)